# how to solve intent redirection in android native app?

Tags: android, redirect, apk, android-manifest

I have problem am using deep link in my application. and when I try to upload update in Google play . they reject the update . reason (intent redirection) when I searched for this issue I fond 3 cases one of them .I tried add exported =false for all your activities except home coz direction code already in home and am already add it

Intent Redirection
Your app(s) are vulnerable to Intent Redirection.
To address this issue, follow the steps in this Google Help Center article

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure about your code you should look at merged manifest and libraries you use. When you open your manifest file, you will see a tab at bottom pane labelled as Merged Manifest, do same check for it. If you cannot found any issue in it, you should update your libraries to the latest version. This problem is mainly caused by 3.party libraries. But owners of these libraries are aware of this situation and they might have corrected their libraries. However, if you use a library that is not fixed, there is nothing to do except removing the problematic library.